# Find what is in a PYC file

Tags: python, pyc

This may be a noobie questions, but...

So I have a pyc file that I need to use, but I don't have any documentation on it. Is there a way to find out what classes and functions are in it and what variables they take? I don't need to code, just how to run it.

Thanks

Comment: Where's the `.py` files that goes with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you stick it on your import path and import it by name, you can use `dir`

```
import foo
dir(foo)
```

you can also use `help'

```
help(foo)
```

to get the docstring. Both of these can be used on anything that `foo` contains as well. Note that bytecode changes between releases so it may or may not work for your version of python. If this is the case, the best that I can say is to try different versions until one works.

---

If you need to recover the arguments for a function, you first get the argcount

```
argcount = f.func_code.co_argcount
```

the arguments are then the first argcount variables of

```
f.func_code.co_varnames
```

This doesn't tell you what the function expects them to be and is only really useful if it doesn't have a docstring but it can be done.

Comment: `dir` won't give you full method signatures.

Comment: Awesome.. This gets me the functions. Is there a way to tell what the functions/class take as variables?

Comment: @lovefaithswing, if help doesn't work on the function, try Glen Maynards suggestion. It's less hacky than what I'm suggesting. For classes, just apply it to the `__init__` method of the class.

Answer (score 9):

As long as you can import the file, you can inspect it; it doesn't matter whether it comes from a .py or .pyc.

```
>>> import getopt
>>> dir(getopt)
['GetoptError', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'do_longs', 'do_shorts', 'error', 'getopt', 'gnu_getopt', 'long_has_args', 'os', 'short_has_arg']
>>> type(getopt.getopt)
<type 'function'>
>>> inspect.getargspec(getopt.getopt)
ArgSpec(args=['args', 'shortopts', 'longopts'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=([],))
>>> help(getopt.getopt)
Help on function getopt in module getopt:
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way **http://depython.com**

Comment: I tried this and all I got back was the help text for the whole documents. ie, a string that said 'This file does x' with no other details

Answer (score 0):

If the code itself has docstrings, and it wasn't generated with optimizations that remove docstrings, you can import the module and peek around:

for foo.pyc

```
import foo
dir(foo)
help(foo)
```

If you decide you do need code, there's [decompyle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/decompyle/).